# Sort multidimensional Array object

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort this kind of array.
It should sorted by "TotalYearyCostWithBonuses" but it doesn't work.

this is what I tried

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a->Cost->TotalYearyCostWithBonuses - $b->Cost->TotalYearyCostWithBonuses;
}

usort($response->Tariffs, 'sortByOrder');
```

this is the array

```
    [10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [LogoImageUrl] => ~/images/anbieter/645211.jpg
        [Tariffs] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IsTieredTariff] => 
                        [Cost] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [TotalYearyCostWithBonuses] => 634.550721
                            )

                        [TariffId] => 881723300
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IsTieredTariff] => 
                        [Cost] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [TotalYearyCostWithBonuses] => 694.550759
                            )

                        [TariffId] => 881725148
                    )
            )

        [Name] => E WIE EINFACH GmbH
    )
```

**Edit**
It was near ... now its working ;)

```
foreach($response AS $item) {
  usort($item->Tariffs, 'sortByOrder');
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Note that in above example the array is already sorted. If you want sort in descending order invert $a/$b: `$b->Cost->TotalYearyCostWithBonuses - $a->Cost->TotalYearyCostWithBonuses;`

Comment: hm, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: ok, its working from now. I had to make an foreach ;) Edited the question with the answer.